# How to write XML to DIV using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, xml, innerhtml

I would like to ask instead of using document.write, how do I write the XML info to a div using innerHTML? I tried to use document.getElementById("box").innerHTML but I am not sure how.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    function loadXMLDoc(dname){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
    }
</script>

<script>
    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    { 
    document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("<br>");
    //instead of using document.write how do I use innerHTML?
    //this is the method i tried:
    //txt = document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    //document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = txt;
    //it is not working, can anyone advice?
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And what happend when you tried it?

Comment: @felix i am not sure what to add. I tried using this but it is not working.
    //the method i tried for innerHTML
    txt = document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = txt;

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, which one? Is it not displayed at all? Or is it not displayed the way you want it to? If so, how do you want it to be displayed and how is it displayed? These are all points which would make it easier for us to help you. "It does not work" is *never* an appropriate problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var xmlText = document.createTextNode('<xml></xml>');
document.getElementById("box").appendChild(xmlText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of the script; it works fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
                var xhttp = null, xml = null, titles = null, html = "";
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                if(!xhttp) {
                    alert("Failed to make the request!");
                } else {
                    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
                    xhttp.send();
                    xml = xhttp.responseXML;
                    titles = xml.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    for(var i = 0, len = titles.length; i < len; i++) {
                        html += titles[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = html;
                }
            }
            window.onload = function(){
                loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The XML I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <title>This is a title</title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>This is a title 2</title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>This is a title 3</title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>This is a title 4</title>
    </book>
</books>
```

And [here is a live version of the script](http://www.allyumassage.com/ajax/xml.html).

Answer (score 0):

XML nodes don't have an *innerHTML* property like that on *HTMLElements*; you have to work with *DOM* methods on the *Nodes* or [**serealise**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer) it into a *String*.

```
var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc('books.xml'), 
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title'),
    xs = new XMLSerializer();
document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = '';
for (i=0; i<x.length; ++i) { 
    // the nodes you want
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += xs.serializeToString(x[i]) + '\n<br />\n';
}
```

Alternatively, `return xhttp.responseText` and work with that, but you won't be able to loop over nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      $(function()
      {
        $.get('books.xml', function(xml)
        {
           var box = $("#box");
           var xmldoc = $($.parseXML(xml));

           xmldoc.each('title', function()
           {
             box.append($(this).text() + "<br>");
           });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you dont want the content to be interpreted as html, then you create a div in the xmldoc.each body (before box.append) that is created by var div = $("<div/>"); div.text($(this).text()); box.append(div);